# Devo checar datas com DateTime ou regex?

Tags: php, string, regex, datetime

Tenho visto duas maneiras diferentes de verificar se uma data é válida.

De uma forma "moderna", com `DateTime`:

```
$date="2014-02-04";
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", $date);

return $dt !== false && !array_sum($dt->getLastErrors());
```

E usando uma expressão regular:

```
$date="2014-02-04";

// regex bem simples, apenas para demonstrar a situação.
return (preg_match("/^[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$/",$date));
```

Não encontrei muito informação comparativa sobre esses métodos. Sei que o `DateTime` é mais moderno, mas isso basta para considerá-lo mais recomendável? Quais são as vantagens e desvantagens de cada método?

Comment: Eu recomendo a utilização da Classe http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php, pois além de ser especializada em datas Expressões regulares devem ser utilizados em último caso, pois é bastante custoso tanto para trabalhar com as mesmas quanto para o servidor. Podendo em alguns casos causar lentidão.

Answer (score 10):

Datas são no fundo números. Mesmo que você declare na forma de string, é mais eficiente representá-las como inteiros.

A classe `DateTime` é especializada, logo, possui todas as otimizações possíveis para se trabalhar com datas.

Expressões regulares são de uso geral e processam strings. Normalmente, têm um custo computacional elevado (normalmente são O(n²)).

Some-se isso ao fato de que é muito mais fácil para um computador interpretar inteiros que strings e você tem a sua resposta.

Via de regra: sempre que houver uma alternativa às expressões regulares, use-a. Expressões regulares são como um canivete suíço: sempre úteis, mas se você tiver um alicate de verdade, por que usar aquele alicate mais ou menos que vem no canivete?

Comment: +1 Excelente comparação com o canivete :)

Answer (score 5):

Não precisa complicar. Use a função nativa `checkdate` do PHP:

https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.checkdate.php

bool **checkdate** ( int *$month* , int *$day* , int *$year* )

Exemplo:

```
if (checkdate(2, 29, 2014)) {
    echo 'Data válida';
}
else {
    echo 'Data inválida';
}
```

Isso vai imprimir na tela: Data inválida. Porque 2014 não é ano bissexto.

Answer (score 4):

É melhor utilizar o DateTime::createFromFormat() mesmo. Foi feito para isso e trata condições que sua expressão regular não trata.

Não sei te dizer qual é a mais rápida (voto no DateTime) pois isso dependerá da implementação e da versão do PHP.

---

Para versões do PHP menores que 5.3 a documentação apresenta esse código alternativo para o DateTime::createFromFormat():

```
static function createFromFormat ($format, $time){
assert ($format!="");
if($time==""){ 
    return new DateClass();
}

    $regexpArray['Y'] = "(?P<Y>19|20\d\d)";        
    $regexpArray['m'] = "(?P<m>0[1-9]|1[012])";
    $regexpArray['d'] = "(?P<d>0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])";
    $regexpArray['-'] = "[-]";
    $regexpArray['.'] = "[\. /.]";
    $regexpArray[':'] = "[:]";            
    $regexpArray['space'] = "[\s]";
    $regexpArray['H'] = "(?P<H>0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])";
    $regexpArray['i'] = "(?P<i>[0-5][0-9])";
    $regexpArray['s'] = "(?P<s>[0-5][0-9])";

    $formatArray = str_split ($format);
    $regex = "";

    // create the regular expression
    foreach($formatArray as $character){
        if ($character==" ") $regex = $regex.$regexpArray['space'];
        elseif (array_key_exists($character, $regexpArray)) $regex = $regex.$regexpArray[$character];
    }
    $regex = "/".$regex."/";

    // get results for regualar expression
    preg_match ($regex, $time, $result);

    // create the init string for the new DateTime
    $initString = $result['Y']."-".$result['m']."-".$result['d'];

// if no value for hours, minutes and seconds was found add 00:00:00
    if (isset($result['H'])) $initString = $initString." ".$result['H'].":".$result['i'].":".$result['s'];
    else {$initString = $initString." 00:00:00";}

    $newDate = new DateClass ($initString);
    return $newDate;
    }    
}
```

E como dá para ver eles também utilizam regex (não se nas versões 5.3+). Mas, regex por regex, use o DateTime::createFromFormat() mesmo.

Answer (score 3):

A expressão regular não é muito boa para fazer validação de datas, visto que você não quer somente validar se existe números ou traços você também quer validar a data.

A expressão que você colocou

```
^[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$
```

Seria responsável por validar a data `"2014-02-31"`, e essa data não existe.

Uma opção seria usar uma expressão regular mais complexa (valida entre 1800-2099 com anos bissextos)

```
^((?:18|19|20)[0-9]{2})-(?:0[13578]|1[02])-31|(?:18|19|20)[0-9]{2}-(?:01|0[3-9]|1[1-2])-(?:29|30)|(?:18|19|20)[0-9]{2}-(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8])|(?:(?:(?:(?:18|19|20)(?:04|08|[2468][048]|[13579][26]))|2000)-02-29)$
```

Mas quanto maior a expressão regular maior o processamento, por isso, recomenda-se  transformar texto no tipo Data como melhor opção, dessa maneira a conversão impede que seja feita com datas inválidas.

Comment: Não... Tipo, nãaaaaaaaaooooo faça dessa forma.

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos Que tal expandir seu comentário pra explicar melhor o que tem de errado com essa forma? É melhor pra todo mundo

Comment: Está explicado na minha resposta logo acima.

Comment: A resposta esclarece bem que a melhor opção é a outra e não esta. Acho bem valida esta resposta por mostrar a outra forma de o fazer e o porque de não usar essa forma @HenriqueBarcelos.